# How can I find what process is starting apps in the background?

Tags: launchd

I keep seeing CIJScannerRegister running. I'd like it to never run. Every time it appears I use `launchctl` to remove its listing and that kills the app. But it reappears later. I know where CIJScannerRegister lives and could delete it, but I would rather get whatever is starting it to not start it. I've looked through `/System/Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons}` and cannot find any matching entry in there. How can I find the process that is launching it and tell it to stop?

Comment: What user is it running as?

Comment: @Mark it is running as myself

Comment: Have you looked in ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Comment: @Mark yes, there is nothing that seems to match in either FQDN or file content.

Comment: Goodlesuggests it is here  /Library/Image Capture/Support/LegacyDeviceDiscoveryHelpers/CIJScannerRegister.app and is a Canon Printer driver https://discussions.apple.com/message/23197490#23197490

Comment: @Mark I knew where it was from the start. I want other applications to not start it. I don't particularly want to delete it if I don't have to. Did you read my question past the first line?

Answer (score 6):

CIJScannerRegister is of no use if you don't have an old Canon Inkjet, but Mavericks really wants to have it running all the time.

It's in /Library/Image Capture/Support/LegacyDeviceDiscoveryHelpers, but if you remove it it will appear again in the form of a "Canon Inkjet Printer Software Update" in the App Store.

The only solution I found was to delete the executable inside the app bundle so the OS thinks it's still installed but it can't run.

In Terminal:

```
killall CIJScannerRegister
cd /Library/Image\ Capture/Support/LegacyDeviceDiscoveryHelpers/CIJScannerRegister.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo rm CIJScannerRegister
```

Comment: El Capitan loves this thing too.  This solution still gold a hundred years out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PPID to find out which process started another process :

`ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm`

PPID referes to the PID of the process who started it.

Comment: The ppid turned out to be `launchd`'s, but that's what I guessed from it being listed in `launchctl`. What I want to know is what entry in what database tells `launchd` it should start this process -- removing it via `launchctl` doesn't appear to be permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Activity Monitor` (from `/Applications/Utilities`), click on the CIJScannerRegister process, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (or use the **Inspect** button or go to **View > Inspect Process**). You will see the *Parent Process:* field show the name and the process id of the process that launched it.